# Scraping from specific part of html based on right click

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, web-scraping

I am building a chrome extension whereby I want to be able to right click on a certain part of a page and then scrape some info from it. So using chrome.contextMenus I'd like to be able to only scrape from the element(one of it's attributes) where I've right clicked. Sort of like the behaviour in chrome when you right click somewhere on a page and select inspect it will open the element view on the page element you right clicked. The reason I want to do this is because there will be a number of similar type elements with different ids(attribute) so I want to be able get only the id of the particular element I'm interested in.

Is this even possible?

I was looking though the [chrome.contextMenus](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contextMenus) documentation and I'm wondering if I know the element type(article)could I set the context menu on that and get the id that is stored in it that way?

Comment: @TobiasGlaus: He's asking about Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your extension has to remember what was the last element under the right click. And content-script suits well for it.

**background.js**

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Get ID",
    id: "menu1",
    onclick: function (info, tab) {
        // send message about context manu action
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
            msg: 'get_id'
        }, {
            frameId: info.frameId
        });
    }
});
```

**content-script.js**

```
let lastClickedEl = null;

// remember last clicked element
document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    if (e.button === 2) { // right click to an element
        lastClickedEl = e.target;
    }
});

// receive message about context menu action
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
    if(request.msg === 'get_id') {
        console.log(lastClickedEl.id); // your code here
    }
});
```